# SML - how to return a real from a function with integers?

Tags: function, int, return, sml

I have the following functions:

```
fun power(0,n):int = 1 | power(k,n):int = n*power((k-1),n)

fun myfunction(1,n) = 1 | myfunction(2,n) = 1
| myfunction(x,1) = 1 | myfunction(x:int,n:int) = (1 div power(n,(x-1))) + myfunction(x,n- 1)
```

What I need to do, is return a real value from myfunction, and not an integer. I tried specifying the return value (myfunction(x:int,n:int):real), I have tried using / instead of div, and also tried changing 1's to 1.0 but nothing seems to work.
Any ideas how I should return a real value? (x and n must be integers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to convert the result of the call to `power` to real:

```
fun myfunction(1, n) = 1.0
  | myfunction(2, n) = 1.0
  | myfunction(x, 1) = 1.0
  | myfunction(x, n) = 1.0 / real(power(n, x - 1)) + myfunction(x, n - 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert an int to a real using [Real.fromInt](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/real.html#SIG%3aREAL.fromInt%3aVAL). Also, use `/` instead of `div` and return `1.0` instead of `1` in the cases where you do it.